# v8 node gyp pass by reference to change value

Tags: c++, v8, node-gyp

I want to implement v8 function using c++ via node gyp, which mutates the function parameter.

```
// c++
using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
  using v8::Isolate;
  using v8::Local;
  using v8::Object;
  using v8::Number;
  using v8::String;
  using v8::Value;

  void Method(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>&args) {
    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate(); 
    // do something to modify args
    // e.g) args[0] = "changed now!"
  }
```

so that I can use it like below.

```
# js file
const str = 'before';
myCppFunction.doSomething(str);
console.log(str);
// I expect str is now 'changed now!'.
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

(V8 developer here.) Define "possible".

The more obvious answer is "no". A variable like `constr str = ...` is a reference to an object on the heap (this object, in this case, being a string). When you call `Method`, a copy of this reference is passed along as a parameter. Reassigning what `arg[0]` points at would not affect what `str` points at, because it's a copy. There is no way for `Method` to change what `str` points at.

Which gets us to the other answer: what if you let `str` continue to point at the same string, but modified that string's characters? V8 won't easily let you do that, because strings in JavaScript are defined to be immutable, but if you try hard enough, C++ will let you modify almost any memory you want. However, this would have very weird consequences; it would "break JavaScript semantics" for the program, because that string would change *everywhere* where it's used. Let me expand your example a bit to explain:

```js
const str = 'before';
const backup = str;  // Another reference to the same on-heap object.
myCppFunction.doSomething(str);
console.log(backup);  // What now?
```

Since JavaScript engines perform various internal tricks that rely on string immutability, this could get even weirder, e.g. strings can be used as part of other strings (so called "cons" or "rope" strings), such as `const rope = str + 'some additional text';`: if you overwrite `str`'s characters now, you'd see that in `rope` as well -- but only if you haven't yet performed any operation that caused `rope` to get "flattened", at which point it's internally turned into full copy of all characters.
Long story short, while this is technically possible, I wouldn't recommend it. (Oh, and also, changing the length of the string object on the heap would constitute memory corruption and result in a crash.)

The obvious alternative is to use a wrapper object, similar to how you would do it if you wanted to implement something like this in pure JavaScript (or Java, or Python, etc):

```js
function doSomething(stringWrapper) {
  strWrapper.string = 'changed now';
}

const str = 'before';
const wrapper = {string: str};
doSomething(wrapper);
console.log(wrapper.string);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your plenty explannation. I understand your point. Originally, I came up with this idea because Javascript native string replace was super low on large json files(1mb ++). This string modification will only happen in the node response middleware, so the modified string wont be used again elsewhere(knowing the side-affect you mentioned). I should playaround with args pointer to modify the chars in it :)

Comment: @DannielLee Again: (1) I would *not* recommend the semantics-breaking approach (too risky, even if right now you can't see all its dangers), (2) you can't change the length of the string, which is probably a severe limitation. -- It's important information that your real aim is to make string `replace` faster, which makes this here an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Ask about what you really want, and you'll likely get better answers.